# How do I identify which factor levels do not significantly differ during within group comparisons using emmeans() in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interaction, emmeans, pairwise

I am currently trying to look at how the likelihood of reaching a particular insect life-stage (in this example 1st instar) is influenced by both temperature (factor: 5 levels - 20, 23, 26, 29, 32 degrees Celsius) and species (factor: 2 levels - HA and AP) using a logistic regression model in R. My model looks like this:

```
eggmodelA <- glm(cbind(No.hatched,No.eggs.added-No.hatched) ~ Temperature * Species, data=eggto1st.1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

A likelihood ratio test revealed the interaction between temperature and species is significant so I wanted to gain within temperature comparisons between species and within species comparisons of temperature. Using the emmeans() function of the emmeans package I was able to gain within group pairwise comparisons for both temperature and species using the following code:

```
Within.species<-emmeans(eggmodelA, specs = pairwise ~ Temperature|Species)
Within.temperature<-emmeans(eggmodelA, specs = pairwise ~ Temperature|Species)
```

What I would like to know is:

1. How do I add letters to the emmeans$contrasts section to signify, within species, which temperatures did not differ significantly in regards to the likelihood of an individual reaching the 1st instar?
2. Is there any way I can add the letters from pairwise comparisons within factors to the plot of my model in R or do I have to do this separately outside of R? If possible I would also like to add some form of indicator on the graph for each temperature detailing if the two species differ significantly or not. I used the following code to gain a plot of the model:

```
emmip(eggmodelA, Species ~ Temperature, type = "response", xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Predicted probability of reaching 1st instar from egg (± 95% confidence intervals)", CI = TRUE)
```

For the letters for the pairwise comparisons I have tried using the cld() function in the package multcompView as follows:

```
cld(Within.species$emmeans, alpha = .05, Letter = letters)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("cld") : 
  no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "emmGrid"
```

Comment: All I can guess is that some other package has masked the correct method dispatch for `cld`. You might get an idea which by doing `methods("cld")` -- I'd be curious what you see. You might try `library(multcomp)` first, or as a last resort, brute force: `emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(...)`

Comment: While you're at it, you might take a look at the [new vignette on CLDs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/re-engineering-clds.html) and how you can show the differences that *are* significantly different, or set a threshold for using letters to show only means that can be shown equivalent within a given threshold.

Comment: @RussLenth Using ```methods("cld")``` brings up the following but I am not sure what it means ```[1] cld.confint.glht* cld.emmGrid*      cld.glht*         cld.summary.glht*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code```. Furthermore using ```emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(Within.species$emmeans, Letter = letters, alpha = .05)``` gives the following error ```Error in emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(Within.species, Letter = letters, alpha = 0.05) : trying to get slot "post.beta" from an object (class "emm_list") that is not an S4 object``` I also do not know what this means as I am still quite new to R.

Comment: The `methods("cld")` result shows that there is a registered methods for `emmGrid` objects, which is contrary to the error message shown in the OP. In the brute-force approach, you should have called `emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(Within.species$emmeans, Letter = letters, alpha = 0.05)` because `Within.species` is a list of two `emmGrid` objects, and it has to be just one.